# get all markers within a given radius in sql

Tags: sql, coldfusion, google-maps-api-3, distance

I'm trying to get all locations stored in the database with an sql statement described [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3.html#findnearsql)

My sql statement is:

```
SELECT TOP(10)
                *,
                (
                    6371 *
                    acos(
                        cos(
                            radians(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_Numeric" value="#FORM.latitude#">)
                        ) *
                        cos(
                            radians( custLat )
                        ) *
                        cos(
                            radians( custLong ) -
                            radians(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_Numeric" value="#FORM.longtitude#">)
                        ) +
                        sin(
                            radians(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_Numeric" value="#FORM.latitude#">)
                        ) *
                        sin(
                            radians( custLat )
                        )
                    )
                ) AS distance
                FROM customers
                HAVING distance < 25
                ORDER BY distance;
```

Problem is I get an error and can't figure out why...
error: `Invalid column name 'distance'.`

on this line: `radians(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_Numeric" value="#FORM.latitude#">)` (the second occurrence)

Why do I get this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did it wrong. Here is solution :

```
SELECT distance FROM

(SELECT TOP(10)

                *,
                (
                    6371 *
                    acos(
                        cos(
                            radians(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_Numeric" value="#FORM.latitude#">)
                        ) *
                        cos(
                            radians( custLat )
                        ) *
                        cos(
                            radians( custLong ) -
                            radians(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_Numeric value="#FORM.longtitude#">)
                        ) +
                        sin(
                            radians(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_Numeric"  value="#FORM.latitude#">)
                        ) *
                        sin(
                            radians( custLat )
                        )
                    )
                ) AS distance
                FROM customers
                ) newTable
                HAVING distance < 25
                GROUP BY distance
                ORDER BY distance;
```

Comment: this gives a different error:
Column 'newTable.distance' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Sorry. Need to put GROUP BY clause between HAVING and ORDER BY.

Comment: you should really edit your answer to contain the correct code, then.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using creating a stored procedure or view in sql server or mysql server.